PyDev 11.0.3: warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run command fails to improve the situation
This is a recurrent question on StackOverflow and I have browsed the history of them. Alas none of those answers apply to the problem I have at hand (I'm an old hand at PyDev and have done this many times), which is that I get the standard warning, which provides the standard run request:
0.10s - warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"E:\Venv\Testing\Scripts\python.exe" "E:\Utility\Eclipse\dropins\PyDev.11.0.3\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_11.0.3.202310301107\pysrc\setup_pydevd_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 2484)

And then I run the command suggested and it completes successfully and without complaint:
(Testing) E:\>"E:\Venv\Testing\Scripts\python.exe" "E:\Utility\Eclipse\dropins\PyDev.11.0.3\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_11.0.3.202310301107\pysrc\setup_pydevd_cython.py" build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
copying build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython.cp312-win_amd64.pyd -> _pydevd_bundle

Yet the complaint is still present on every debug run. It's not gone away.
Now that is a puzzle. It has always worked as it should in past, over many versions of PyDev and on many platforms I've used.
Aside: I am using 11.0.3 because 12.0.0 (which is released) is not available:
https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/releases/download/pydev_12_0_0/
But I was probably using 11.0.3 on this very PC before the rebuild (I'm reinstalling after a rebuild of my PC post a nasty malware infection, gotta love Windoze).

Not a complete answer, as in the original issue with 11.0.3 is not in any way diagnosed or resolved. But today Fabio released 12.0.1 (bless his soul) and available as a zip which I unzipped into the Eclipse dropins folder and am now on PyDev 12.0.1 and this issue is not apparent. The reminder to build debugger speedups is gone.
Mildly surprising as I removed the 11.0.3 dropin and so suggests the target of debugger speedups build is not in the dropins folder but elsewhere under the eclipse folder.
